# Android best design practice for accessing SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-intentservice

In my Android app, I have a local DB (SQLite) that the app needs to query for data. The query may take a long time (>5 seconds) so I am avoiding using the main UI thread for that. The returned data may also be rather large (> 1 MB).

Between AsyncTasks, Threads, ExecutorService, and IntentService, (and maybe more) what's the best class/API to use in Android to do this? Are they all more or less the same in terms of what they offer? Or is there a clear winner and a better suited class for database access?

Comment: I think it's quite opinion based, but currently, the preferred option seems to be to use a `Loader` class (i.e. a `CursorLoader`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer, I'm sure you can predict, is "it depends".

If you are writing a set of related calls (for example that will sync your database using an API), then I would want to use an IntentService since it's a long running operation not directly tied to your user interface.

If it's a one-time operation hitting the database to get a result set, I would lean towards the loader framework/`CursorLoader` to fetch data for your UI. `AsyncTask` is an option, although it's really a more general purpose threading mechanism. Also, consider an ORM framework that does threading work or maintains a queue of work items for you.

I can't really think of a case where managing a Thread directly would be the best option. It's very low level and lots of room for error when there are nicer abstractions over it.

Comment: What about `Loaders`?

Comment: Yes good point, not sure how I forgot about that! I updated my answer